Draw a topological puzzle using tikz
I see this drawing of the impossible figure 8 puzzle. How can I recreate it using Tikz package?


This sounds like a job for knots/braids/spath3. Maybe start by recreating the path ignoring the cuts. You also might just ask the author since they have used TeX as well.

I converted the drawing to svg with Inkscape and then copied the path into the tikzpicture environment.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{333333}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]

\draw[line width=.475192pt] {svg "m 86.381502,38.064658 c 2.483224,5.79465 -2.869074,11.397756 -8.942091,11.397756 m -3.779957,-7.269152 c -0.05237,-2.976562 -0.242535,-6.545682 2.85116,-8.124913 2.994477,-1.528244 7.167178,-0.354157 9.026151,2.418458 M 73.827574,50.675088 73.702172,43.761469 m -4.260893,12.873633 c 2.23931,-0.509876 4.034896,-1.581989 4.36838,-4.212664 M 61.90341,54.074705 c 1.90996,2.348177 4.704623,2.920065 7.537869,2.560397 m 0.640786,-15.708259 c -2.875964,0 -7.329784,-0.02205 -9.019258,2.793284 -1.836924,3.059246 -1.394576,7.60815 0.840603,10.354578 M 74.551043,38.872188 c 4.677061,0.179147 2.711979,4.085886 -0.901238,4.085886 -3.691763,0 -5.417065,-3.606327 -0.841978,-4.028006"};

\draw[line width=.475192pt] {svg "m 74.562067,47.461501 c 4.620564,0.296277 3.192914,4.107931 -0.683506,4.107931 -3.5829,0 -5.561761,-3.748264 -0.942577,-4.098286"};

\draw[line width=.712964pt,mygray] {svg "m 76.600188,56.53037 c 2.568663,-2.118043 7.566805,-4.327038 6.913615,-7.696341"};

\draw[line width=.712964pt,mygray] {svg "m 82.959833,47.023284 c -1.706012,-4.018358 0.282497,-10.153385 5.23379,-10.167165 2.094618,-0.0055 3.130902,0.385851 3.766178,2.357822 0.555349,1.719792 2.239309,2.975187 2.13596,4.91684 -0.168124,3.129527 -4.985745,4.503431 -6.996303,6.216333 -1.630218,1.387683 -2.002289,3.824054 -3.790982,5.050507 -1.992644,1.367014 -4.723913,-0.206703 -6.708288,1.132749"};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



A suggestion would be to fix the parameters to make less convoluted. For example the linewidth.

Not an answer.
I had an idea that one could use a double lines to effect the intersections, as shown here.  Interstingly, the effect only works if you use two seperate \draws.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,double distance=1pt]
\draw[white,double=black] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[white,double=black] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


